# i just downloaded StdDraw3D.java, i want to try to run it...but it give these error

Tags: java, 3d

i just downloaded StdDraw3D.java, here is the link for the code:
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdDraw3D.java.html

i want to try to run it...but it give these error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/j3d/Node
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:252)
```

Comment: You need to download the dependencies too

Answer (score 0):

You need to download [Java 3D API libraries](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html).